Link between channel capacity and mutual information
I am confused about the following: How can channel capacity, which is measured in bits per second, be equal to (the maximum) mutual information, which is measured in bits? I am confused. Could someone clarify?

Channel capacity is measured in bits per use (or bits per symbol transmitted), or in other words also just in bits.

@TobiasFritz I still don’t get it :(

You're subject to a misunderstanding: channel coding happens in discrete time, not continuous time. That's Shannon's mathematical model to which his mutual information formula applies. Channels in continuous time are simply a different matter (which I personally know nothing about).

Alright, so you say "channel coding happens in discrete time, not continuous time". Thanks. Now I am supposed to know why channel capacity, which is measured in bits per second, be equal to (the maximum) mutual information, which is measured in bits?
I am very sorry but no one here is providing a comprehensive answer, just some vague sentences that is supposed to be an answer. Please be direct, write your reasoning out, so that I can get what is going wrong in my reasoning. If you can't, then simply don't answer anything.

Both leonbloy's answer and my comments have explained why channel capacity and mutual information do have the same unit (namely bits). This is a precise and complete answer to the question as you've phrased it. However, this does not explain why channel capacity is equal to maximal mutual information, because they could still be different quantities having the same units. Their equality is quite difficult to prove, and that's what Shannon's channel coding theorem achieves. If you have any specific questions about the proof of that, then I suppose that would be a different question.

@TobiasFritz Thanks. 1. What is meant by "bits per channel use", why is that the same as bits? 2. "channel coding happens in discrete time, not continuous time" what is the difference in terms of the unit of channel capacity, aren't they both times? Why is that exactly relevant to my question. Please write a comprehensive answer explaining all of this and I will accept your answer.


How can channel capacity, which is measured in bits per second, be equal to (the maximum) mutual information, which is measured in bits?

The Shannon entropy of a pure random variable is indeed measured in bits (assuming we are taking logarithms in base two). Now, we must take the context into account. If the random variable models an information source (as in the first Shannon theorem), then, to say that the entropy of the random variable is $5$ bits is to say that each time the source emits a symbol (= a realization of the random variable) it produces $5$ bits of information. That is, the entropy of the source is actually "$5$ bits per symbol emitted".
If we are instead dealing with a channel:
we define the capacity as $C = \max_{p(X)} I(X;Y)$. As explained above, if we speak of the pure random variables involved (input/output of the channel), this is defined in bits. But in the context of the channel itself, it should be understood as "bits per channel use". For example: a maximized mutual information of $5$ bits means that we can (asympotically) transmit $5$ bits of information... at each channel use, that is, each time we input a single value $X$ and receive a single value $Y$. If we know that the time unit (slot) corresponds to a real time $t$  then it's trivial to convert this to "bits per second" (in the same example, if the channel is used $100$ times per second, then its capacity would be $5 \times 100 = 500$ bits per second).
That applies for a discrete-time channel, in which the random variables can take continuous values, but the time is discretized.
When we deal with a countinous-time channel, with no apriori time discretization, then we typically have some frequency limit (bandwidth). With some work (related to Nyquist theorem), this limitation turns to imply something akin to a time discretization (in the sense that we can send, during a time $T$ a finite number of real values), hence, again, we can convert from "channel use" to seconds. See eg. here.

"If we know that the time unit (slot) corresponds to a real time , then it's trivial to convert this to "bits per second" Yes I know, but what about Entropy, isn't it just in bits? If so, why do we then say that they are equal?

The entropy of a random variable (in bits) is actually in bits per variable realization.
The entropy of a source is in "bits per symbol emitted".
The capacity of a channel is in "bits per channel use".

Is "bits per symbol emitted" then the same as "bits per channel use"? If not, how can channel capacity be equal to (the maximum) mutual information? Please answer my question directly.

Could you please clarify?  1. What is meant by "bits per channel use", why is that the same as bits? 2. "channel coding happens in discrete time, not continuous time" what is the difference in terms of the unit of channel capacity, aren't they both times? Why is that exactly relevant to my question. Please write a comprehensive answer explaining all of this and I will accept your answer.

The capacity in Shannon's theorem is a different quantity, not the number of bits transferred in a unit of time.
To transmit a message through a noisy channel, we encode it in a transmitted sequence which is larger than the original message, to account for the corruption because of noice. The capacity is measured as the number of bits of the original message per one symbol of the transmitted encoded message.

I am still confused, sorry. How it that definition of entropy then linked to channel capacity, which is measured in bits PER SECOND?

There are two definitions of channel capacity (see e.g. the book "Elements of Information Theory"):

Information Channel Capacity is defined as supremum mutual information (entropy reduction). Mutual Information measures the quantity of information in a static context (between two variables or distributions) and is expressed in bits. It's a measure of information content.
Operational Channel Capacity is defined as the
highest rate in bits per channel use at which information can be sent reliably (which means with arbitrarily low probability of error) via a noisy channel. Clearly, this involves time because it describes a rate of information flow through a channel over time. Thus, its unit incorporates both information content and time (bits/s or bits per channel usage).

Shannon's second theorem established that the information channel capacity is equal to the operational channel
capacity. The difference in units between channel capacity and mutual information arises because they are measured in different contexts and serve slightly different purposes in information theory. But, there are no contradictions.
